# Can't do multiple selects on a table for columns

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, linq

I'm trying to do get multiple columns from inside this `Person` table. But I seem to only be able to get one property here (`Address`). Why can't I do multiple selects here?

```
largeThings = DbContext.Set<Things>()
                .Where(ep => ep.CreatedDate > dateTimeYesterday)
                .Include(ep => ep.People

                    .Select(p => p.Person)
                    .Select(p => p.Address)).ToList();
```

I tried to use an anonymous object like:

```
largeThings= DbContext.Set<Episode>()
                .Where(ep => ep.CreatedDate > dateTimeYesterday)
                .Include(ep => ep.People
                    .Select(p => p.Person)
                    .Select(p => new { p.Address, p.FirstName })).ToList();
```

But this throws a Navigation property error. Is there any other way I can select multiple columns here?

I want to be able to get both `FirstName` and `Address` from this `Person` table.

Comment: You get address because you select only address. Please show the exact error from your second attempt

Comment: In the first example. I want to add a select to get a nother column from `Person`. If I add another Select, it just goes deeper into the object which I don't want.

Comment: `The Include path expression must refer to a navigation property defined on the type. Use dotted paths for reference navigation properties and the Select operator for collection navigation properties.`

Comment: I don't want to change the underlying data model though.

Comment: On the first you use Thing, on the next Episode, the error is saying Episode has no Person. It has nothing to do with the select, which is just fine

Comment: It is not very clear what are you trying to achieve here. Please be more specific about it.

Answer (score 0):

You can't use `Include` to only get couple columns from the other table. You either get them all or have to use custom selects to get just the data you want.

```
largeThings = DbContext.Set<Things>()
                .Where(ep => ep.CreatedDate > dateTimeYesterday)
                .Select(ep => new {ep, ep.People.Select(p => new {p.Person, p.Address})});
```

Answer (score 0):

The purpose of `Include` is to include in the query result the whole object.

As I understand there is a 1 to 1 relation between the `Things` class and the `People` class, therefore have a look at the following code:

```
largeThings = DbContext.Set<Things>()
    .Where(ep => ep.CreatedDate > dateTimeYesterday)
    .Select(ep => new 
        { 
            ep.People.Person,
            ep.People.Address
        }).ToList();
```